# Using function random() with sass to choose random variables

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have the following variables in my Scss file:

```
$flat-blue: #42a5f5;
$flat-green: #26a69a;
$flat-orange: #ffa727;
$flat-red: #ef5350;
$flat-purple: #c561d6;
```

I found a CodePen [here](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/lKvwy) that change a random value between two numbers, and it seems to work nicely.

Is there a way to use this function random to choose one of my variables?

my CSS:

```
.avatar {
    width: 43px;
    height: 43px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    background: $flat-green; //here should be the result of this function
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 43px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color:white;
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

My HTML structure:

```
<article data-value="<%= subscriber[:id] %>"
       data-status="<%= subscriber[:status] %>"
       data-user="<%= subscriber[:subscriber][:user_id] %>"
       data-profile="<%= subscriber[:profile_id] %>">
<div class="bg">
    <div class="avatar">
        <%= avatar_url(subscriber.profile.user.avatar, subscriber[:subscriber][:name]) %>
    </div>
</div>
</article>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to put all those colors into a single array list and then use the random() function with nth()?

Comment: @clive how can i do that ?

Comment: @Harry how can i do that ?

Comment: @vbotio: Something like [this](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/85bd952e61cd38f26d1f016d3bde968f)?

Comment: Read the docs, give it a try, update the question with the code if/when you get stuck

Comment: @Harry this "worked", my problem is that the number of avatars is dynamic. It could be any number and they "cant" have the same bg color. How can I use a "for" ?

tried something like this:
˜@for $i from 1 through 500
  .avatar:nth-child(#{$i})
    background: random(5)

Comment: does it actually need to be random, or just that each avatar needs a different bg color?

Comment: @andi each avatar needs a different bg color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't "random", but it will take the list of colors that you define in sass, and assign `.avatar:nth-child(n)` to the nth color in that list.  So as long as you define at least as many colors as there are avatars, each one will get a unique color.  If you have more avatars than colors, this will just loop through the colors repeatedly.

```
$avatarBgColors: #42a5f5, #26a69a, #ffa727, #ef5350, #c561d6;

@for $i from 1 through length($avatarBgColors) {
  .avatar:nth-child(#{length($avatarBgColors)}n + #{$i}) {
    background-color: nth($avatarBgColors, $i);
  }
}
```

This compiles into:

```
.avatar:nth-child(5n + 1) {
  background-color: #42a5f5;
}
.avatar:nth-child(5n + 2) {
  background-color: #26a69a;
}
.avatar:nth-child(5n + 3) {
  background-color: #ffa727;
}
.avatar:nth-child(5n + 4) {
  background-color: #ef5350;
}
.avatar:nth-child(5n + 5) {
  background-color: #c561d6;
}
```

Comment: did not work. It has the same color for all avatars :/

Comment: It worked for me.  Did you check that the SASS compiles to CSS correctly?  Are your avatars not actually siblings of each other, like you originally said (in which case, the nth-child structure would need to be altered)?

Comment: yes, it is compiling correctly and yes they are siblings. What should I do ?

Comment: please edit your question to show the HTML structure, or create a codepen to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Here is my fiddle to show that it works: https://jsfiddle.net/md4pvgcz/

Comment: That's not HTML, that needs to be compiled into HTML.  Please show the final HTML structure, including at least 2 avatars within it.  (BTW it seems that your code will NOT compile into something that has the avatars as siblings.)

Comment: look what happens to your fiddle if we have multiples divs https://jsfiddle.net/md4pvgcz/1/

they just dont show the colors

Comment: In that fiddle, the first 5 divs show unique background colors, and the rest don't show a background-color because there were only 5 colors in the list and there was no default background color defined.  If you added more colors to the list, more divs would have backgrounds.

Comment: thats my problem. I have 5 colors, but I have multiple avatars... the colors needs to be sorted. I cant add more colors

Comment: ok, I understand...  you have more avatars than colors, so it's not possible to give each one a unique color.  Do you just want to loop through the colors, so that avatar #6 will have the same color as avatar #1, etc?

Comment: I`m not sure why, but it is compiling everything to .avatar:nth-child(5n + 4) {
  background-color: #ef5350;
}